# vb script to connect to database in access

Tags: vbscript

I need to connect, using VB Script, to a Access database and display the contents of a table. can any one find out the error in the below code.its for connecting to database

Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim cnnLogin
    Dim rstLogin

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM employee"
Set cnnLogin = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

cnnLogin.Open ("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb), *.accdb};" _
    & "DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("database2.aacdb"))

 cnnLogin.Execute(strSQL)
```

End Sub

Comment: What error is it saying?

Comment: This is classic asp, correct?  Which server are you on?

Comment: NO THIS IS not classic asp .its vb6 script

Comment: and at which line is your error? perhaps the one with "Server" in it? show all your code

Comment: Thought so (hence my question).. Like BugFinder said, you should use _Set cnnLogin = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")_ Your Server.MapPath is also not needed then.. that's also classic asp code.